# My dog has disappeared

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard, skyrim-hearthfire

In the early stages of my game I bought Vigilance (the dog) from the Markarth stables. I then went on to build a house and adopt children, one of the children asked me if they could keep the dog. I replied yes as I wasn't really using him that much.

I recently tried to buy an armoured troll and was told to dismiss my other animal. Assuming it was Vigilance, I headed back to my house looking for him, but he is nowhere to be found.

I have already been married and escorted Barbas so I cannot think of any other ways to clear my animal companion slot. I'm on Xbox 360, can anyone help?